# fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, mingw32, rc4-cipher

I try to compile a C file which decrypts and executes an rc-4 encryped shellcode with virtual alloc.

Now I get an error:

> "In file included from rc-4.c:2: rc4.h:62:11: fatal error:
>   openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory
>    #include <openssl/opensslconf.h>/* OPENSSL_NO_RC4, RC4_INT */"

My compile command is: 
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc rc-4.c -o test.exe -lcrypto

At first mingw32 gave me the error that rc-4.h could not be found. 
I fixed this by copying the rc-4.h in my current directory and included it with  #include "rc-4.h"

the first two lines of the code

````
```
#include <windows.h>
#include "rc4.h"
```
````

how the rc-4 shellcode should be decrypted and executed:

```
int lpBufSize = sizeof(int) * PAYLOADSIZE;
        LPVOID lpBuf = VirtualAlloc(NULL, lpBufSize, MEM_COMMIT, 0x04);
        memset(lpBuf, '\0', lpBufSize);
        RC4(RC4KEY, payload, (char*) lpBuf, PAYLOADSIZE);
        MessageBox(NULL, (char*) lpBuf, "Test", MB_OK);
        return 0;
```

the expected output should be the compiled test.exe file

Comment: Can you translate that error message in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MinGW64 because that's what is installed here. I'm aware of the tag "mingw32", hoping it's OK.

**1. Compiling**

The header file `rc4.h` lives in the path `<path-of-installation>/<version>/mingw64/opt/include`, so this has to be given as an argument to `-I`:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -c -I "<path-of-installation>/<version>/mingw64/opt/include" rc-4.c -o rc-4.o
```

You could as well set `CPATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, see [The C Preprocessor: Environment Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).

**2. Linking**

*Note: Because you didn't provide enough source code I could not try this.*

The library file `libcrypto.a` lives in the path `<path-of-installation>/<version>/mingw64/opt/lib`, so this has to be given as an argument to `-L`:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -L "<path-of-installation>/<version>/mingw64/opt/lib" rc-4.o -lcrypto -o test.exe
```